# Download files of two types (*.bat and *.txt) using WinSCP get command

Tags: windows, winscp

I am trying to download files of type `*.bat` and `*.txt` using WinSCP `get` command and put it in `D:\example` folder as shown below:

```
get /zjpw/*.* D:\example\
```

By above line I am getting all different type of files, but I want to get only `.bat` and `.txt` files. How do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To download `.bat` and `.txt` files from `/zjpw` folder only:

```
get /zjpw/*.bat /zjpw/*.txt D:\example\
```

---

To download files even from subfolders:

```
get /zjpw/* D:\example\ -filemask=*.bat;*.txt
```

---

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get